# How can I make jQueryUI icons appear disabled?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, icons

Is there a way to disable the icons in jquery? For example I am using ui-icon-circle-triangle-w and ui-icon-circle-triangle-e for "prev/next" and I would like to disable "prev" when at the beginning of the list and next when at the end etc.

Answer (score 8):

I guess this should have been obvious but it wasn't in the main documentation on how to use the icons. You just add the class `ui-state-disabled` to the element. So for example to do it through JavaScript you might do:

```
$('<selector>').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set .ui-icon to not display, which should also hide the icons.  You may or may not need the "!important" part.

```
.ui-icon { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks but I actually wanted the icons to still display but appear disabled (grayed out). See my answer for the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

This is old but I ran into today so I figured I would clean it up. .addClass('ui-state-disabled') will apply the css to give it that disabled look. But if you have events bound to the icon it will still fire. You also have to make sure your js knows when its disabled. Maybe using if hasClass('ui-state-disabled'). But just adding the css class doesn't "disabled" the icon.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the diagonal "se" handle without the icon the best is :

```
.ui-icon { background-image:none     !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add css `opacity:0.7` on your element. I think this is useful not only for text but also for the icon or other element in your element.

I wrote a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kugqjh3y/)

The key component is:

```
.disable{
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

... and this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kugqjh3y/2/) with icon

Comment: This answer was flagged by the system as "check for low quality".   I can see that it is actually an answer, but it likely would be more helpful if you gave a bit more context - for example showiung the syntax how to add that.   Correct grammar might also save your question from reviewers ticking it hastily as "low quality - delete".  I fixed the grammar, but only you can add the necessary context.

Comment: @GreenAsJade I amended my answer.

Comment: Nice!   I took the liberty of elaborating slightly, because another thing that triggers alerts is answers that depend solely on links :)   I hope you don't mind my intervention.   Thanks for contributing!

Comment: @GreenAsJade your suggestion is good for me, I will never mind, thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

you can't disable them because they are not 'html' elements so the best way is by using 'unbind()' method like: $('#icon-plus-sign').unbind('click');